# How to view number of downloads of packages from Ubuntu Software centre?

Tags: package-management, software-center, downloads, packaging

Is there a way through which I can see the number of times an application or package from the Ubuntu Software Center has been downloaded?

If not, is there some sort of way in which I can view the number of times a package has been downloaded on the Ubuntu distro?

**NOTE** I want to know the universal downloads, not just the downloads that I've made of a particular application.

Comment: I don't think either statistic is tracked...

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit ? Do you mean how many times YOU downloaded the package or how many time ANY user of Ubuntu downloaded it ?

Comment: If you use `apt-get` you can track down the count by checking `/var/log/apt/history.log*`

Comment: @heemayl Maybe the OP can clarify. I think you are telling how to find how many times it was downloaded locally, but the OP seems to me to be asking how to find out how many times it was downloaded world-wide.

Comment: @Mawg  I've edited my question- I want to know the universal downloads

Comment: @heemayl edited question

Comment: That's what dupe asks too, best that I can tell.